# Web deployment task failed. Destination not reachable

Tags: azure

I've been successfully using Azure for months. Today I'm getting the following error when I publish from via Web Deploy from Visual Studio 2013

Error   5   Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("waws-prod-hk1-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

I tried downloaded a new Publishing Profile from the Azure Dashboard and turning off my firewall - no change.
I can't ping the listed server.

It seems to be the same issue as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/83d4e635-2851-4526-b21b-31101d00aa86/web-deployment-task-failed-errorcouldnotconnecttoremotesvc?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I've seen this occur if there were not enough deployment slots available. In my case upgrading from `B1 Basic` to `S1 Standard` corrected the issue immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem for a couple of days (sometimes I could published and sometimes not).
The problem was my internet configuration (not related to Microsoft or Azure in anyway).
To solve this issue I disconnected my modem (its actually modem+router) for 10 min and reconnect it and it was fixed!

Hope it will help someone someday...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It would appear that Azure was in a 'challenged' state. 
It's working fine now..

Comment: No idea, sorry. I just waited and tried again a day later.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was disabling and re-enabling my network adapter.

The reasoning is, quite possibly naive, that having Fiddler running during a deployment will fail but it also changes the network state and that state continues 
to exist even after exiting Fiddler (which disables the proxy).